# How to dispatch multiple actions one after another

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my react / redux application I often want to dispatch multiple actions after another.

Given the following example: After a successful login I want to store the user data and **after that** I want to initiate another async action that loads application configuration from the server.

I know that I can use `redux-thunk`to build an action creator like this

```
function loginRequestSuccess(data) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(saveUserData(data.user))
    dispatch(loadConfig())
  }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. When the first `dispatch`returns, is the state already changed by all reducers listening for that action? I'm wondering if the two dispatch calls are run strictly sequential.
2. Is this approach considered best practice for dispatching multiple actions? If not, what would you suggest alternatively?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have looked at redux saga, based on generator/yield that may fit what you want. It can be difficult at first look, but if you want to take control of what will be sequential or parallel, try this http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.html

Comment: While dispatch is sequential and sychronous, ReactJS will batch updates and run its update (render, etc) asynchronously, so you might only get one render. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes redux-thunk allows you to do as you say, and yes it is a best practice for dispatching multiple actions (one that I prefer over the alternatives because of it's simplicity). The state is indeed updated as soon as you dispatch (by the time it returns), which is why you are given a function to retrieve the state in a thunk, instead of simply a reference to the state. In that way you can alter the state with one dispatch, and then call getState() to get a reference to the new state to read from if you need to.

Comment: could you please share the implementation or link to any relevant article for the same.

Comment: It looks like there are some examples here: https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea4d0a6ce56ee479fe8b356e099f857e otherwise for an article it looks like someone wrote something about it here: https://codepen.io/stowball/post/a-dummy-s-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react

Answer (score 4):

`redux-thunk` is exactly what you are looking for. I consider it very good practice.

To answer your question, indeed when the first dispatch returns the state is already changed by the called reducers.

Comment: Yes, redux-thunk is good for dispatching multiple actions but it doesn't guaranty that all is sequential, isn't it?

Comment: Within the same dispatcher all actions are sequential. In the case described above `saveUserData` is always before `loadConfig`

Answer (score 1):

I know its a late response :-P You can do this by using Redux-Thunk and also checkout Redux-Saga. Redux Saga provides an amazing way to handle loads of actions at the same time. Below is an example of dispatching multiple actions using Redux-Thunk

```
function getAndLoadSider(moduleName){
    return function(dispatch){
        return doSomeApiCall(someData).then(function(item){
            let _item = someOtherFunction(item.collections);
                let _menuData = {
                    name: item.name,
                    key: item.key
                };
            return new Promise(function(res, rej){
                dispatch(actionOne(_menuData));
                res(_item);
            }).then((_item) =>  dispatch(actionTwo(_item)))
    }
}
```

Above method works well for your case when one action is dependent on the first. This is a promise based approach. If you don't like to do a lots of Promise coding I recommend you go for Sagas. Check out this link https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ComposingSagas.html where you will learn how to compose sagas. Learning curve is steep; but once you are done, Sagas will make you a ninja redux dev.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: why dont you give example with saga? you mentioned it and might give comprehensive answer. We appreciate all-around points