# How do I call redux actions sequentially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux

I'm aware I need to use promises but cant put it into code to achieve what I want.

So I have 3 redux actions:

```
getAllCoins()
getUserCoins()
setUserCoinPortfolio(a, b)
```

The set action requires the returned values from both of the get actions, therefore it needs to be called after those functions have completed.  Both gets can be fired at the same time.  This is what I initiate the two calls:

```
 refresh = async () => {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    this.props.getAllCoins();
    this.props.getUserCoins();
    this.setState({refreshing: false});
};

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.refresh();
}
```

Should I combine these into one action? Should I keep them separated but how do  I structure the calls?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dispatch multiple actions one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616330/how-to-dispatch-multiple-actions-one-after-another)

Comment: I believe you are doing some api call in actions and you can do your next dispatch in the then part when you got the result for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using asyn you can wait for first two actions and once those completed you can call set. Something like below.

```
refresh = async () => {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    await this.props.getAllCoins();
    await this.props.getUserCoins();
    this.setState({refreshing: false});
};
```

or

```
refresh = async () => {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    await Promise.All([this.props.getAllCoins,this.props.getUserCoins]);
    this.setState({refreshing: false});
};
```

Comment: Think this is what I'm looking for, but need to use values set by those 2 gets

So should this work: 
    `await this.props.getAllCoins()
    await this.props.getUserCoins()
    this.props.calculateUserCoinPortfolio(this.props.allCoins, this.props.userCoins)` ?

Comment: you can store the results in variables which are coming back form await calls like below `const [result1,result2] = await Promise.All([this.props.getAllCoins,this.props.getUserCoins]);`

Comment: So if I make my redux actions return a value I can do the above, perfect thank you!